# Vectorize code that operates on 3-D matrices

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I want to organize the data returned by `sph2cart` as a matrix with vector elements, and operate on each element in this matrix (vector-vector or vector-scalar calculation). Here is an example wher I achieve this:

```
lightV = zeros(1, 1, 3);
lightV(1,1,1) = 0.5;
lightV(1,1,2) = 0.4;
lightV(1,1,3) = 0.7;
[Az El] = meshgrid(0:60:360, 0:15:90);
[x y z] = sph2cart(Az*pi/180, El*pi/180, 1);
refV = zeros(size(Az,1), size(Az,2), 3);
radius = zeros(size(Az,1), size(Az,2));
for i = 1:size(Az,1)
    for j = 1:size(Az,2)
       refV(i,j,1) = -x(i,j);
       refV(i,j,2) = -y(i,j);
       refV(i,j,3) = z(i,j);
       radius(i,j) = dot(refV(i,j,:), lightV(1,1,:));
    end
 end
```

However this looks somewhat redundant, how could I make it more terse?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can vectorize your code like so:

```
S.lightV = [0.5, 0.4, 0.7];
[Az, El] = meshgrid(0:60:360, 0:15:90);
[S.x, S.y, S.z] = sph2cart(Az * pi/180, El * pi/180, 1);
S.refV = cat(3, -x, -y, z);
S.radius = sum(bsxfun(@times, S.refV, reshape(S.lightV, 1, 1, [])), 3);
```

Note the usage of `cat` to concatenate along the third dimension, and the combination of `bsxfun` and `sum` to replace the dot product inside the nested for loop. I've also bound everything together in one struct `S`.

Comment: Does struct also support similar functionality ? Since all these data imply directions, i would like to convert them as struct with .x .y .z field to make my code more readable.

Comment: Sure, but it's pretty readable as is. I've modified the answer to use a struct.